# Broadcast UDP message in LAN to detect IP cameras

Tags: ios, networking

I am trying to build a small programm for my iPhone which allows to detect devices on my local network (especially IP cameras). I know that some of those support protocols like UPnP and I have been playing around with that as well, but I now want to implement the communication between my iPhone and the camera completely by myself without relying on a library.

My approach is to send a broadcast message out to the local network and parse the responses that are received. For example, in order to detect UPnP devices on the local network, the message that is broadcasted needs to have the following content:

```
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:255.255.255.255:1900\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:ssdp:all\r\nMX:1\r\n\r\n
```

I am a bit familiar with network programming in C, so I want to write the code for the communication in C and integrate in my Objective-C later on.

I am currently doing the following:

```
// Create socket
int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

// Enable broadcast messaging
int broadcastEnable = 1;
int ret = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcastEnable, sizeof(broadcastEnable));

// Configure the port and ip we want to send to
struct sockaddr_in broadcastAddr; // Make an endpoint
memset(&broadcastAddr, 0, sizeof broadcastAddr);
broadcastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.255.255", &broadcastAddr.sin_addr); // Set the broadcast IP address
broadcastAddr.sin_port = htons(1900); // Set port 1900

// Create the broadcast UPnP request
char *request = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST:255.255.255.255:1900\r\nMAN:\"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST:ssdp:all\r\nMX:1\r\n\r\n";

// start the broadcast
success = sendto(sd, request, strlen(request), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&broadcastAddr, sizeof broadcastAddr);
```

Now, I am stuck at this point, since I don't know how to process any answers. Will the replies from the UPnP devices come in on the same socket? I believe it should be able to receive the incoming replies with recv() of recvfrom() but I am not sure how exactly to implement them. Do I have to create a new socket or can I just the existing one? Does the socket have to be bound using bind()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing is that you are trying to send SSDP packet for Service Discovery. So you should send this packet to Multicast address 239.255.255.250 instead of 255.255.255.255.

Beside that you can receive the response to discovery request on same socket. Just call the recv() function on this socket.

Furthermore I hope you are using Mac OS X (as you are developing for iOS) so you already have Python installed. Just open the terminal and type **python** and copy paste following python code,

```
import sys
import socket

SSDP_ADDR = "239.255.255.250";
SSDP_PORT = 1900;
SSDP_MX = 1;
SSDP_ST = "ssdp:all";

ssdpRequest = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n" + \
                "HOST: %s:%d\r\n" % (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT) + \
                "MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n" + \
                "MX: %d\r\n" % (SSDP_MX, ) + \
                "ST: %s\r\n" % (SSDP_ST, ) + "\r\n";

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(ssdpRequest, (SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT))
print sock.recv(1000)
```

This code will send a discovery packet and will print the first response that it receives from network. I am just sharing this code as you can easily test it and understand the code even if you don't know python. And of course this can be translated to C easily.

I hope it helps.